# Using same database tables for different projects in django postgresql

Tags: django, postgresql, django-models

I am new to using Django framework. I want to use the same database(PostgreSQL) tables for 2 different projects. I was able to access the same database from two different projects. But how to access the tables?

Firstly, I have models in project1

```
class employees(models.Model): 
    employeeID = models.IntegerFiled()
    employeeName = models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

This would create a `project1_employees` table in the database. I want to access this table in project2. If I have the same model in the project2 and migrate it creates a new table `project2_employees` in the same database. These are two entirely different projects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the second project change the meta of your model this way:

```
class employees(models.Model): 
    employeeID = models.IntegerFiled()
    employeeName = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'project1_employees'
```

And then make fake migrations:

```
python manage.py migrate --fake
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `managed = False` in the second project model `class Meta:`. This will prevent the migrate code from creating the table. For more information see:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/options/#managed

What you need to consider is whether you think the projects will diverge enough they will end up needing separate databases/tables.